# Empty else for case when

Tags: mysql

I'm updating multiple columns using case when. I want no action taken on cases not handled by when. I read this could be accomplished by using a begin end, but this doens't work for me.

My syntax is:

```
update site_configuration set value = 
    case 
        when attribute_name="hostname" then "abcdef" 
        when attribute_name="backend" then "ab" 
        when attribute_name="col" then "col" 
        else 
            begin 
            end
    end case 
where uid="abcdef";
```

Does this syntax look right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use just

```
else `value`
```

In this case the value of the `value` column will be left the same

Instead you can add one more condition to your `where`

```
where uid="abcdef" AND attribute_name IN ('hostname', 'backend', 'col')
```

in this case you just omit `else` clause